# Merging arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays of data:

```
array(2) {
  ["12:15"]=>
  string(84) "http://form.horseracing.betfair.com/horse-racing/010108/Catterick_Bridge-GB-Cat/1215"
  ["12:20"]=>
  string(77) "http://form.horseracing.betfair.com/horse-racing/010108/Southwell-GB-Sou/1220"
}
```

and

```
array(2) {
  ["12:15"]=>
  string(90) "http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=446323&r_date=2008-01-01&popup=yes"
  ["12:20"]=>
  string(90) "http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=446250&r_date=2008-01-01&popup=yes"
}
```

I want to merge these based on time, so I end up with an array of values where times in both arrays match only.

```
array(2) {
  ["12:15"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(84) "http://form.horseracing.betfair.com/horse-racing/010108/Catterick_Bridge-GB-Cat/1215"
    [1]=>
    string(90) "http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=446323&r_date=2008-01-01&popup=yes"
  }
  ["12:20"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(77) "http://form.horseracing.betfair.com/horse-racing/010108/Southwell-GB-Sou/1220"
    [1]=>
    string(90) "http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=446250&r_date=2008-01-01&popup=yes"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you ought to be storing the data in an array keyed by the time.

Comment: @Keyo thanks i updated my arrays to be keyed by time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of the answers on offer and some extra Google foo, solved it using the following:

```
$c = array_merge_recursive($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't the following do trick?

```
$arr1 = array('time' => '14:00', 'rp' => 'blah');
$arr2 = array('time' => '14:00', 'bf' => 'yadda');

if ($arr1['time'] === $arr2['time']) {
    $mergedArray = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
}
```

Comment: should that be == instead of === ??

Comment: @Vinothbabu, `==` would work, as it matches values, using `===` would be the same but it would also match the type as well, so there's not really any need to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($all_arrays as $a) {
  if (!isset($result[$a["time"]])) {
    $result[$a["time"]] = array();
  }
  $result[$a["time"]] = array_merge($result[$a["time"]], $a);
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have any number of these time arrays. It's probably a good idea to store the array like this:

```
$times = array(
   '14:00' => array(...),
   '15:00' => array(...),
   etc...
);


$temp = array();
foreach($time_arrays as $time_array) {
    if(isset($temp[$time_array['time'])) {
      $temp[$time_array['time'] = array_merge(temp[$time_array['time'], $time_array);
    }
    else {
      $temp[$time_array['time'] = $time_array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array('time' => '14:00', 'rp' => 'blah');
$arr2 = array('time' => '14:00', 'bf' => 'yadda');
$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2 ;

var_dump( $arr3 ) ;
```

Gives

```
array
  'time' => string '14:00' (length=5)
  'rp' => string 'blah' (length=4)
  'bf' => string 'yadda' (length=5)
```